# Regex to get array number from string

Tags: regex

I want to get array number from string.
Example:

```
Input: "@[Anonymous:2] abccdef, @[Sales:5]"

Output: [2, 5]
```

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what language you use but you can leave a comment and I would gladly update my answer for you and help. **Edit**: The OP specified [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) in the comments below.

```
@\[\w+:(\d+)\]
```

The result for each match is in `capture group 1`

You can check your input and regex at [regex.com](https://regexr.com)

```js
var s = "@[Anonymous:2] abccdef, @[Sales:5]"
var r = /@\[\w+:(\d+)\]/g
var m = r.exec(s)
var a = []

while (m != null) {
  a.push(Number(m[1]))
  m = r.exec(s)
}

console.log(a)
```

Comment: `@\[\w+:(\d+)\]` performs slightly better and also captures the whole number (your current regex will only capture the last digit of a two or more digit number)

Comment: @ctwheels, thanx, check it now, you can run it here, it is only code snippet to help debugging his results

Comment: @msoliman I've simplified your Javascript and regex pattern (you don't need to escape everything in regex, plus the `+` was not in the capture group - whilst it should). Notice that SO has the snippet functionality and also includes a builtin display for the console.

Comment: @ctwheels thanx, appreciated

Comment: thanks @msoliman and @ctwheels , but i got bug is example `@[Anony mous:2] abccdef, @[Sales:5]`, if `Anony mous` has `space characters`, the output not show 2

Comment: i solved this bug with regex `@\[[a-zA-Z_ ]+:(\d+)\]`
anyway many thanks
@msoliman
@ctwheels

Comment: @TrầnQuốcVũ you can use `[^:\]]+` assuming only one colon and right square bracket is possible within the `[]`